# Why do xyplot() and dotplot() generate different plots with the same arguments?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

Why do the following codes generate different plots?
What's the difference between xyplot() and dotplot()?

```
library(lme4)
library(lattice)
str(Dyestuff)

xyplot(reorder(Batch,Yield)~Yield,Dyestuff,ylab = "Batch", jitter.y = TRUE, pch = 21, aspect = 0.32,
   xlab = "Yield of dyestuff (grams of standard color)",
   type = c("p", "a","g"))

dotplot(reorder(Batch, Yield) ~ Yield, Dyestuff,
          ylab = "Batch", jitter.y = TRUE, pch = 21, aspect = 0.32,
          xlab = "Yield of dyestuff (grams of standard color)",
          type = c("p", "a"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question refers to the fact that the *lines* (not points) shown in `xyplot` and `dotplot` are different.

[image]

This is perhaps not a full answer, but the key to your answer seems is in the documentation to `panel.xyplot`, `panel.dotplot` and `panel.average`.

Specifying `type = "a"` has the effect of calling `panel.average`.

It seems that `xyplot` and `dotplot` average the data differently. While `xyplot` averages `Batch` values per `Yield` (which is not very meaningful here since `Batch` is a categorical `factor` variable), `dotplot` averages `Yield` values per `Batch`.